# How to use range projection in a sorting algorithm?

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm trying to wrap my bonehead around the ranges. So decided to implement some basic sort procedures as a range algorithm and like in the `std::ranges::sort()`. I peeked its implementation but didn't understand how to make use of `projection`:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>
#include <ranges>

namespace sort {

namespace ranges {

struct insertion_fn {
  template <std::random_access_iterator I, std::sentinel_for<I> S,
            typename Comp = std::ranges::less, typename Proj = std::identity>
  requires std::sortable<I, Comp, Proj>
  constexpr I operator()(I first, S last, Comp comp = {}, Proj proj = {}) const {
    if (first == last)
      return first;

    std::size_t N = std::ranges::distance(first, last);

    I last_iter = std::ranges::next(first, last);

    for (std::size_t i = 1; i < N; ++i) {
      for (std::size_t j = i; j > 0 && comp(*(first + j), *(first + j - 1)); --j) {
        std::iter_swap(first + j, first + j - 1);
      }
    }

    return last_iter;
  }

  template <std::ranges::random_access_range R, class Comp = std::ranges::less,
            class Proj = std::identity>
  requires std::sortable<std::ranges::iterator_t<R>, Comp, Proj>
  constexpr std::ranges::borrowed_iterator_t<R> operator()(R &&r, Comp comp = {},
                                                           Proj proj = {}) const {
    return (*this)(std::ranges::begin(r), std::ranges::end(r), std::move(comp), std::move(proj));
  }
};

inline constexpr insertion_fn insertion;

} // namespace ranges
} // namespace sort
```

This test fails:

```
TEST_CASE("Insertion: Make use of range projection") {
  namespace stdr = std::ranges;
  using person = std::pair<std::string, std::string>;

  std::vector<person> people{
      {"tintin", "detective"}, {"snowy", "lifeguard"}, {"haddock", "captain"}};

  auto expected = people;
  stdr::sort(expected, std::less{}, &person::first);

  auto test = people;
  sort::ranges::insertion(people, std::less{}, &person::first);

  REQUIRE_EQ(test, expected);
}
```

My question is how to where to handle `projection` into the this implementation. Sorry for the long code snippets.

Comment: Where are you getting this code from?

Comment: From my Github: https://github.com/syntaxonly/sort 
Still working on them so didn't push some changes to remote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of the projection in sort is to change the comparison being used. For example:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> words = {"a", "quick", "brown", "fox"}; 

// sorts by normal lexicographic order, so you get [a, brown, fox, quick]
std::ranges::sort(words);

// same, but reversed, so [quick, fox, brown, a]
std::ranges::sort(words, std::greater());

// sorts words in increasing order by size, so [a, fox, brown, quick]
// (or quick, brown)
std::ranges::sort(words, std::less(), std::ranges::size);
```

Your code is simply comparing the elements directly:

```cpp
comp(*(first + j), *(first + j - 1))
```

Which itself is a long form of:

```cpp
comp(first[j], first[j-1])
```

Instead of comparing the elements directly, you need to compared the *projected* elements:

```cpp
comp(proj(first[j]), proj(first[j-1]))
```

A different way of thinking about it is that a projection is a convenient way of alternating part of the comparison - so you can keep the `<` part (the `Comp` parameter) but just change which part you're `<`-ing (the `Proj` parameter).

Comment: Idk, i changed the comparison on the for loop in sort but now i got an error like: "error: ‘proj’ cannot be used as a function"

Comment: @syntaxonly That's because you have to use `std::invoke(f, x)`, not `f(x)` - and the same for `comp`.

Comment: Umm, is it like this `std::invoke(comp, std::invoke(proj, first[j]), std::invoke(proj, first[j - 1]));`?

Comment: @syntaxonly Yep, like that.